# MSBuild TeamCity Windows Service Output

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, csproj

I am using **TeamCity** with Visual Studio. Build artifacts are staged to a file share in the **_PublishedWebsites** folder for web projects. I have a **PowerShell** script that deploys those web applications. Works great!

I needed to create a **Windows Service** project. Problem is those artifacts are staged in the root directory with all artifacts from the entire solution. What do I need to do to my **Windows Service** project file and **TeamCity** configuration to get it to stage the Windows Service project output in it's own folder?

Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Found a solution which customises the Targets output for Web Applications that publishes to _PublishedWebsites to a _PublishedApplications folder.

Simple, neat, useful trick: http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2011/03/21/published-applications-aka-_publishedapplications.aspx.

Even simpler is this Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications